# Multple records from one tabe based on id from other

Tags: mysql

Hello on I am trying to write a mysql query that select multiple records from one table based on the id from another
 here is my query

```
SELECT o.total, o.shipping, o.order_date, oc.product_type, oc.quantity, cu.first_name,
cu.last_name, CONCAT(cu.address1, cu.address2) AS address
FROM `orders` AS o 
INNER JOIN order_contents as oc ON o.id=oc.order_id
INNER JOIN `customers` AS cu ON o.customer_id=cu.id
WHERE o.customer_id = '217';
```

On the inner join for order_contents i would like to select multple records if the are more than 1

What sort of join do i use, Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start selecting from `order_contents` table

```
SELECT o.total, o.shipping, o.order_date, oc.product_type, oc.quantity, cu.first_name, cu.last_name, CONCAT(cu.address1, cu.address2) AS address
FROM order_contents AS oc
INNER JOIN `orders` as o ON oc.order_id = o.o_id
INNER JOIN `customers` AS cu ON o.customer_id=cu.id
WHERE o.customer_id = '217';
```